# SonataUserBundle's admin lists/inserts to fos_user_user and not my user table

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I 'm using `FOSUserBundle` + `SonataUserBundle` in Symfony2.
I extended Sonata's `BaseUser` like this:

```
namespace ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser{
[...]
```

and my `config.yml` is:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class:     ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\Group  

sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    class:                  # Entity Classes
        user:               ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:              ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\Group
```

it logins into `/admin` area uing users in `users` table; 
But when viewing users list in admin it shows none of users in `users` table;
When I create new user using `Add User` in admin page it adds user to `fos_user_user` table instead of `users` table.
it also created `fos_user_user` & `fos_user_group`.

What is the problem?
How can I change working table of `SonataUserBundle`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem:
When I extend the `Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser` & `Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup` I should not generate userbundle in Application namespace using `app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle --dest=src` so `new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),` shouldn't be loaded in `AppKernel.php`.
Instead in `parameters.yml` I should add these:

```
sonata.user.admin.user.entity: ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\User
sonata.user.admin.group.entity: ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\Group
```

Now it works with `users` table as `ar1y4n\UserBundle\Entity\User` entity uses it.